# Calculate Daylight Savings Time (DST) on SQL/Database level

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, dst

My location in **Sydney, Australia**. The dates that I explain will be in UK or Australia date format.

Observe the following:

- 2010-04-15 04:30:00.000 => 15/04/2010 14:30:00 EST (UK date format - Add 10 hours)
- 2010-11-05 01:00:00.000 => 05/11/2010 12:00:00 EST (UK date format - Add 11 hours)

Both these times are retrieved from the database in UTC format and then **calculated on the Web level** whether +10 or +11 hour is applicable.

In Australia, Daylight Savings Time (DST) transition dates vary year by year. The transition dates are usually Early April and Late October.

So how accurate would the Web calculation be? If this year the transition date is a few days later (say 03/04/2010), but the Web calculation bases on a fixed date (say 01/04/2010), wouldn't that mean that the days in between will be off by 1 hour when displayed (due to the fixed calculation nature to a specific day of the month)?

I believe the transition dates is not pre-determined and is actually announced to the public. Is that assumption true?

If not (that means the DST dates are pre-determined), would I be able to do the calculation outside the Web level (on the **SQL/Database level**)?

The database is **SQL Server 2005** and I'm using **Report Definition Language (RDL)** to display the fields in UTC time. If SQL/database level is not the best way, how do I work out +10 or +11 and format the time accordingly to show the right time?

Thank you.

Comment: In Australia, is there some fixed pattern regarding transitions? The reason for this question is that, there is a TZ database which keeps track of these variations. Check if these variations are captured in TZ database.

Comment: Another example of why using an integerial epoch time in the DB works wonders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database is a bad choice for it: it has less information than c# or .net to work it out. .net uses the registry which is kept upto date periodically by patches. SQL Server would have to have a table with date ranges and offsets.

The transitions are fixed because of scheduling (flights, trains ,whatever). IIRC it only changed once at short notice recently in Australia for some Olympic games and it caused chaos around the world. In 2007 the [US changed](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=931836) but this was known in advance.

By fixed, it's the "last Sunday" type fixed even if the date varies.

I would leave it in the web code: the DB does not know where your caller is for example, the web site can work it out.

Comment: I'm using Report Definition Language (RDL) to display the fields in UTC time, how do I work out +10 or +11 and format the time according to show the right time?

Comment: AFAIK, SSRS does not support timezones. It can be done in javascript but I'm not sure this would be useful.

Comment: In our scenario, we have the users enter the scheduled Dates and Time in text. This way they do not have to be stored in GMT format. This solves our issue because scheduled Dates and Time varies by location. Sydney it would be GMT +10 and Perth it would be GMT +6. So even if we were to generate a report with the correct DST adjustment, we still have to decide whether to +10 or +6 which complciates it even more (even though we have the location data to determine which to add). Basically now when something is scheduled, it will be appended with Start time and End time suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is whoever wrote this app does not quite understand UTC, its value, and how to use it.  The database is the correct location for the dat, but the system is not using UTC as intended.

If you use UTC, then all your date arithmetic should use UTC.  In the database.  It is currently using a saved UTC and then converting at some (doesn't matter if seciond tier or third) other layer; some other library.  Half UTC, and Half something else.  Have you considered historic dates, as in what is the DATEDIFF() between 15 Feb 2010 and today ?

This eliminates the concern re DST in Australia or Greenland.; and concern re what date/time the changeover actually happens.  Everyone is using Greenwich Mean Time for that particular day.

Do all you date arithmetic in the db, in UTC. And display the result (only) in the local time zone, which as you have it, is the web layer, based on the user.

Many systems have dropped that last step altogether, and display in UTC only, regardless of the user's time zone.

Comment: A good point. We show Swiss time in our Web GUI for users in the far east for example (mainly for legacy reasons but no.one asked for local time...)

Answer (score 0):

The database can handle DST for you. Use its time zone conversion functions to go from whatever zone you stored the dates in to whatever zone you want to get for the user.

MySQL has CONVERT_TZ(), I don't know what other RDBMS's have.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm using SQL server 2005.